# Where are Adobe InDesign (OLE) COM Automation interfaces documented?

Tags: com, automation, ole, adobe-indesign

I am developing a .NET application (using C#) that needs to massage some Adobe InDesign files and output their content as PDFs. I could use InDesign's scripting but the COM interfaces seem a bit cleaner for this non-interactive work.

Unfortunately, I have to guess at the semantics of InDesign's COM interfaces because I don't know where they're documented. I can't find anything on Adobe's support site.

So the question: Where do I go for semantics of InDesign's COM interfaces?

Thanks in advance, everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found something close to what I needed. Since InDesign's COM classes are really the same thing as its Javascript interface:

[Scripting Tutorial for CS3](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/products/indesign/scripting/pdfs/indesign_cs3_scripting_tutorial.pdf)

[JavaScript Reference for CS3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/pdfs/IllustratorCS3_JavaScript_Reference.pdf)

The interfaces haven't changed very much from CS3 to CS4. Sadly, almost all of the methods take `object` arguments so it is hard to write useful code in strongly typed languages without a lot of casting.

Comment: For more recent versions (CS6) check out https://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/sdk/eula_cs6.html or https://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/sdk.html